# Community Promotion Ads — 2020

Tags: discussion, community-ads

2020 has come! But… oops, where did the time go? It’s already March! Belated as it is, it’s time for a refresh of **Community Promotion Ads**!

#### What are Community Promotion Ads?

Community Promotion Ads are community-vetted advertisements that will show up on the main site, in the right sidebar. The purpose of this question is the vetting process. Images of the advertisements are provided, and community voting will enable the advertisements to be shown.

#### Why do we have Community Promotion Ads?

This is a method for the community to control what gets promoted to visitors on the site. For example, you might promote the following things:

- interesting biology research sites
- useful resources for practitioner and student alike
- cool events or conferences
- anything else your community would genuinely be interested in

The goal is for future visitors to find out about *the stuff your community deems important*. This also serves as a way to promote information and resources that are *relevant to your own community's interests*, both for those already in the community and those yet to join.

#### Why do we reset the ads every year?

Some services will maintain usefulness over the years, while other things will wane to allow for new faces to show up. Resetting the ads every year helps accommodate this, and allows old ads that have served their purpose to be cycled out for fresher ads for newer things. This helps keep the material in the ads relevant to not just the subject matter of the community, but to the current status of the community. We reset the ads once a year, every December.

The community promotion ads have no restrictions against reposting an ad from a previous cycle. If a particular service or ad is very valuable to the community and will continue to be so, it is a good idea to repost it. It may be helpful to give it a new face in the process, so as to prevent the imagery of the ad from getting stale after a year of exposure.

#### How does it work?

The answers you post to this question *must* conform to the following rules, or they will be ignored.

1. All answers should be in the exact form of:

   ```
   [![Tagline to show on mouseover][1]][2]

      [1]: http://image-url
      [2]: http://clickthrough-url
   ```

   Please **do not add anything else to the body of the post**. If you want to discuss something, do it in the comments.
2. The question must always be tagged with the magic [community-ads](/questions/tagged/community-ads) tag. In addition to enabling the functionality of the advertisements, this tag also pre-fills the answer form with the above required form.

#### Image requirements

- The image that you create must be 300 x 250 pixels, or double that if high DPI.
- Must be hosted through our standard image uploader (imgur)
- Must be GIF or PNG
- No animated GIFs
- Absolute limit on file size of 150 KB
- If the background of the image is white or partially white, there must be a 1px border (2px if high DPI) surrounding it.

#### Score Threshold

There is a **minimum score threshold** an answer must meet (currently **6**) before it will be shown on the main site.

You can check out the ads that have met the threshold with basic click stats [here](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/ads/display/4049).

Answer (score 12):

[image: Coronavirus (Covid-19) Information]

Comment: If you make a minor update, such as a blank space with HTML code `&nbsp;` I can take away my downvote. Maybe in March 2020 I was unhappy with WHO's cowardly silence in [this interview](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=UlCYFh8U2xM) (pretending to have internet connectivity issues to not answer the question, but asking to take the next one after the connection became unambiguously clear), but it was in the passed and I don't want to downvote this anymore. I see to have one on Chem.SE too, but I'd be happy if we were to do the same for that one too.

Answer (score 10):

[image: Common topics on Matter Modeling SE]

Comment: Modeling of bio-materials, protein folding, DNA origami, artificial nanotechnology using bio-molecules, and more!

Comment: Private beta will start next week (4/27)

Answer (score 9):

[image: Chemistry Question? Ask at Chemistry.StackExchange.com!]

Answer (score 9):

[image: Stack Exchange Q&A site proposal: Synthetic Biology]

Comment: Synthetic Biology has about 7 days left to get 50 active SE users to commit. I suggest you add the "science helping science" ad to the Meta sites of Space.SE, Robotics.SE, etc. (after adding Synthetic Biology to it). See this: https://area51.meta.stackexchange.com/a/32548/190792

Answer (score 7):

[image: Public Resource for Biological & Medical Literature]

Comment: The idea is to let people know about this major literature resource that is free, not-for-profit and does not violate author's copyright. Presumably one would need to OK this with PubMed.

Answer (score 6):

[image: Google Scholar]

Comment: Surely Google can pay for its own ads.

Comment: @David. Certainly, and fair point indeed! Though, I'm not doing this for Google's sake. **I always propose it as a way to expose unaware question askers to a useful, easy, and accessible searching tool for primary literature.** (I figure, if we're always telling people to provide support for their answers, why not show them a place to easily find sources!).  [In other words, it's exposure for knowledge/learning sake!!!]

Answer (score 5):

[image: Free online access to books in the life sciences]

Comment: To make people aware of a resource that they can use to research questions before posting.

Answer (score -6):

[image: Tagline to show on mouseover]

Comment: Surely it should be "Find, steal and make money out of it."

Comment: I thought it is similar to NCBI-PMC or google scholar but why it is unrecommended?

Comment: @AlwaysConfused If you make a small edit to this post, such as adding a blank space with HTML code: `&nbsp;` , then I can take away my downvote. I think you had enough of them here!